# How Can I Implement Horizontal Swipeable Button?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, swipe, gesturedetector

Let's say I have a button at the top of the screen and a recycler bellow that. I want the button horizontally swipeable and swiping the button will change the recycler data list. I can implement it using ViewPager but I don't want swiping anywhere in the screen. Swipe option will be only in the button area. Any suggestions about how can I do that?

Comment: You will need to override the onTouch of your button and detect the gesture there using MotionEvent. Create a callback in your button to relay the information to the recycler view.

Comment: thanks a lot! It worked.